# Make object method_missing behave like class method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I have created a class which I have some constant hashes. I'd like to type `Myclass.myhash.hashkey` and to show the value of the hash. Right Now I have created a similar behavior with `method_missing` but I have to initialize the object, so I am calling it like `Myclass.new.myhash.hashkey` and it works. Here is my code so far:

```
class Myclass
  def initialize
    @attributes = []
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    @attributes << name
    if @attributes.length == 2
      eval("#{@attributes.first.upcase}[:#{@attributes.last.downcase}]")
    else
      self
    end
  end

  MYHASH = {
    id: 1,
    description: "A nice hash",
    hashkey: "hash key"
  }
end
```

How can I do it without initialize and without `new` so it won't create an object of `MyClass` everytime?

**Update:**
The first question was explained by toro2k but I don't know if using it I can have the behavior of my second question...

**Question 2**
I have many openstructs in my class, how can I define them as a class methods dynamically without every time adding something like:

```
  def self.myhash
    MYHASH
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `OpenStruct` object instead of the `Hash`:

```
class MyClass
  MYHASH = OpenStruct.new(id: 1, 
                          description: 'A nice Ostruct', 
                          hashkey: 'hash key')
  def self.myhash
    MYHASH
  end      
end

MyClass.myhash.id # => 1
MyClass.myhash.description # => "A nice Ostruct"
MyClass.myhash.foo # => nil
```

**Update** You could replace constants with class instance variables like this:

```
class MyClass
  def self.myhash
    @myhash ||= OpenStruct(id: ...)
  end
end

MyClass.myhash.id
```

Or you could use class variables and `cattr_reader`:

```
class MyClass
  cattr_reader :myhash
  @@myhash = OpenStruct(id: ...)
end

MyClass.myhash.id
```

Or you could get rid of the `myhash` method and access the constant directly:

```
class MyClass
  MYHASH = OpenStruct(id: ...)
end

MyClass::MYHASH.id
```

Comment: Should I also add require 'ostruct' ? I tried it with require ostruct and without it but it didn't worked for me (I am using ruby 2.0.0-p195, maybe I am doing something wrong).

Comment: It should work even without `require 'ostruct'`. What error do you get?

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `OpenStruct' for Myclass:Class , maybe it has to do that I am trying to run it from inside rails?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I've already updated the answer, you have to use `OpenStruct.new(...)` and not `OpenStruct(...)`.

Comment: oh that's right, I didn't see that. Great, it is working! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution for my second question also:

```
  class << self
    Myclass.constants.each do |constant|
      define_method(constant.to_s.downcase) do
        eval("#{constant}")
      end
    end
  end
```

I just have to add it at the end of the class to work, after I have defined all the openstruct variables.

Comment: Nice, but consider passing `false` to the [`constants`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-c-constants) method so you don't define methods for constants defined by base classes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am not sure I have completely understand it. I should monkeypatch the constant and add there a false? Otherwise it will automatically be included in all the classes that the module is included? Is there any better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Write `Myclass.constants(false)` instead of `Myclass.constants`, the former returns only constants defined inside `Myclass` while the latter returns all the constants defined by `Myclass` and all its ancestors.

Comment: You're welcome, and here comes another :-). You can replace `eval("#{constant}")` with just `const_get(constant)`.